# Multiple Stack Overflow accounts for same email address?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, multiple-accounts

I just registered on Stack Overflow. I found out that I already had an unregistered account associate with the same email. I tried to merge them but failed.

The problems are: when I use my Gmail account login, it goes to new account, but if I reset the password, it goes to the old unregistered one. If it's possible, I still want the reputation from the old account.

Comment: It's sad I found I have 3 accounts on the same email: /users/244857/lei      
/users/153587/lei      
/users/512653/lei

Comment: Are your accounts still separated? We can see about merging them together, if so.